# Django Post request not sent on button click

Tags: python, jquery, django, post, web-applications

I am trying to create a simple web app in Django and trying to use Ajax so the page will not refresh. The only goal of this app is to have a form that takes some user input and does not refresh when the form is submitted. However, for some reason this does not happen when I click the button. Here is the Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Create product here</h2>
<div>
<form id="new_user_form">
  <div>
  <label for="name" > Name:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
  <label for="email"> email:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="email"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="password" > password:<br></label>
  <input type="text" id="password"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submitme"/>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/text/javascript">
  $(document).on('submitme', '#new_user_form', function(e)){
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'/user/create',
      data:{
        name:$('#name').val(),
        email:$('#email').val(),
        password:$('#password').val(),
      }
      success.function(){
        alert('created')
      }
    })
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Here is my main urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from testapp import views
import testapp
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', testapp.views.index),
    url(r'^user/create/$', csrf_exempt(testapp.views.create_user))
]
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testapp.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        User.objects.create(
            name = name,
            email = email,
            password = password
        )

        return HttpResponse('')
```

And lastly the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

The aim of this was when the button is clicked, it should send a POST request to the backend which creates a object of type User and saves it to the database. However, for some reason when I click submit, no POST request is sent according to the Network tool on Chrome. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: `$(document).on('submitme', '#new_user_form', function(e)){`- this doesn't look right, surely the first argument should be `'click'`?

Comment: Hi tried this : $('#submit').click(function()) instead of the previous header but it did not make a difference and no POST request is sent either

Comment: That will only work if you give the submit button `id="submit"`

Comment: Yes did that, still no post request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'accounts/index.html')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

your code should look more like this. Here I use the default django auth system so there is no real need of your `model.py`, at least not for now. Also look at the renders i have added - with the `HttpReponse` your page will reload.  The email is automatically saved with the `form.submit()`

The SignUpForm should be simply:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required.')
```

Comment: Just tried this solution, still no POST request is sent from the submit button. I also don't understand what you mean by no need for Models.py - without the database where would the data be saved?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/
look at the django docs for this, it will make it clearer how it works in the Django world I think

Comment: Also, models.py is diffrent from the database. It's like an explanation of what should the columns of a table in the database be.

Comment: Models.py creates the tables in the database when the migrate commands are run is my understanding. However, my main problem with this is the Post command is not being sent when the button is clicked and there's no obvious reason why its doing this and the solutions suggested here havent worked so far for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but **I'd like to help you with the following changes:** 
**I edited and updated** my post since few parts of my earlier suggestions were not applicable in your case (since ajax contentType was OK in your case and so on...), so I cleared my answer for your purpose:

**1.**

in **the HTML form**, the input names should be given at the input fields, since that way easier to submit input HTML Form values with AJAX:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

<input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>

<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
```

The submit button should be changed like this:

```
<button type="button" name="submitme" id="submitme">Submit</button>
```

**2.**

your **AJAX call** should be reformulated like this (I think the trailing slash is missing from your **url** and the **data** could be in simpler format than you made, and the click function is on button id now. And the closing brackets are cleared on the code:

```
<script type = "text/text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#submitme').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/user/create/',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert('created');
        }
    })
  })
});
</script>
```

And your view should look like this to get the ajax submitted data and save as new User (with very small modification):

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        new_user = User.objects.create(
            name = name,
            email = email,
            password = password
        )

        new_user.save()

        return HttpResponse('')
```

This way it must work now. I hope this will be in help of you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant this answer will be. But the only reason why "POST" request is not getting created for you is because you have written in your JS `<script type = "text/text/javascript">` instead of `<script type = "text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding method="POST" and action="{% url 'url_name' %}" to html form. Also add name to url for create user.